# Need to convert the source currency to dollar in oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table XXX where we have customers billing info , like source currency where customer paid, date etc.
Now I need to convert this source currency value to Dollar amount based on the billing date made and multiplied by dollar exchange rate on that particular day.(exchnage_rates table).

So in exchnage rates table we have only the dates from last years, where as in xxx table we ahve the dates from more than 10 years(lets say from 2000 year). If the dates are not matching from xxx table it should pick the minimum date from exchange table and calculte the value.
At the end if the dates are missing in the exchange table which are in xxx table
it should pick the value from minimum date of exchange table.

[image]

we have subs date in customer table, based on that date, src currency should be converted to dollar value with the exchnage rate on that date from the exchnage rate table. If dates from cust table  are not there in exchange table for that src currency, then it should pick the starting date of that exc_src, to exc_target. Here the example is in cust_table we have subs_date as 01-oct-2020/01-oct-2016, as this date is not available in exchange table then it should pick the minimum date which is 01-jan-17 for exc_src as EUR and exc_tgt=USD

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions, something like this:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(er.rate, er_first.rate) as effective_rate
from t left join
     (select er.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by currency order by date) as next_date
      from exchange_rate
     ) er
     on t.currency = er.currency and 
        (t.date >= er.date and (t.date < er.next_date or er.next_date)) left join
    (select currency, max(rate) keep (dense_rank first order by date) as first_rate
     from exchange_rate er
     group by currency
    ) er_first
    on t.currency = er_first.currency
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach, I am unable try the logic . I have added some more description to my question. Please help me